# New Brother Laser Printer install without needing disk

Tags: network-printer

Is there a file I can copy from driver disk to my file server that would allow me to install clients without needing to have disk each time a client needs to install drivers?

It is setup as wired ethernet.

Comment: Is the printer hosted by a server, or will each user be connecting directly to the printer?

Comment: At the very least, just copy the driver installer from the disk to a network location.

Comment: Connecting directly to the printer. But that doesn't have to be like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Best practice:** Install the printer on the server and share it from there. Each other client will then receive the driver automatically from the server when they connect to the shared printer.

No installer needed, and you can manage the queue and set defaults and such.

**Not as good:** Download the latest installer for the printer from the Brother support website. This will be guaranteed to have all the necessary drivers and files for installing the printer and you won't need the CD any longer.

Comment: Note that you'll need to install on the print server all of the print drivers needed by your clients (i.e. both 32 & 64 bit), not just the one that matches the server's architecture.